# Flask: request files are empty for zip file uploaded using Javascript DataForm

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, flask

I'm trying to build a Node.js application that will zip user files into a tar archive and upload them, and a Flask app that will receive the downloads and process them. I've set up a local Flask app to print any files and form names in the request.

```py
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def list_files():
    print(request.headers)
    print('FILES', request.files)
    print('FORM', request.form)

    return 'Success!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=3131)
```

And in a JavaScript portion of my code, I create a tar archive, then try to upload is using `tar`, `node-fetch`, and `formData`.

```js
const tar_archive = tar.c({ gzip: true, cwd: script }, ["."]);
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', script.pipe(through2()), 'name.tar.gz');
// I also tried the line below, but it doesn't work either
// formData.append('file', script, 'name.tar.gz');

const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3131`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData
  });
```

Unfortunately, the files don't appear in the Flask app itself.

```sh
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------244643127282477847663641
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 215
User-Agent: node-fetch/1.0 (+https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Connection: close
Host: localhost:3131


FILES ImmutableMultiDict([])
FORM ImmutableMultiDict([])
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2021 19:02:31] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Do you know what might be causing this? I've used the JavaScript code for a while, and it's worked for several years. Only when I introduce Flask do things break.